# Modify cursor position in R prompt

Tags: r, cursor, prompt

I would like to have the position of the cursor in a R prompt in the last line, not the first one, is it possible?:

```
text<-"Save all celltypes in a single sheet (1), or separated in sheets (2), (Note: choosing number 1, gives you the opportunity to add means and sums); Write 1 or 2"
text<-paste(strwrap(text,60), collapse="\n")
response <- as.numeric(readline(paste(text)))
```

In this code, the cursor is too close to the last word "in" of the first line

Answer (score 0):

Try this, basically just adding a space character into the paste command after the strwrap. Won't move the cursor to the last line, but will provide a buffer between the text and the cursor.

```
text<-"Save all celltypes in a single sheet (1), or separated in sheets (2), (Note: choosing number 1, gives you the opportunity to add means and sums); Write 1 or 2"
text<-paste(strwrap(text,60)," ", collapse="\n")
response <- as.numeric(readline(paste(text)))
```